Screen Mirroring on Samsung Hospitality TV with Tizen Platform
I want to open screen mirroring on samsung smart tv . via a tizen web application
I found this code
Samsung Hospitality Open Guide Sound Mirroring on stackoverflow.
But when i call the function :


 launchApplication("mobile_screenmirroring_1").



in my code  I get this error : No Matched application found.

From above link, since Tizen 6.0, needs to use this code: new tizen.ApplicationControlData("uri",["SoundMirroringGuide"]);

Hello, Thanks for your response,
Yes I used new
tizen.ApplicationControlData("uri",["ScreenMirroringGuide"])
But when I call the Function with :
launchApplication("ScreenMirroringGuide");  I get an error saying :
No matched application found.
Thank you.
